# kivy: how to use scikit-learn for android

Tags: scikit-learn, kivy, apk

I want to use Kivy to develop an Android app that includes scikit-learn. After I use buildozer to package it, the app doesn't run properly. I want to ask if Kivy framework doesn't support scikit-learn and how to use scikit-learn for android.

I have set the requirments in buildozer.spec as 'requirements = python3,kivy,matplotlib,numpy,scikit-learn,scipy',but it doesn't work.